# Creating areas with different levels of resolution in the same model?

Tags: mesh, topology, geometry

How can more resolution be added to certain parts of a model? For example, on this piece of popcorn the green areas need more detail. How can the whole model stay low poly and only quads while adding the extra detail?

[image: high and low poly models]

Comment: is that a heart or something?

Comment: @Vince It's a popcorn kernel. : )

Comment: @Animatoring if that was helpful, let us know so we can mark this as duplicate and it will show a link to that answer more prominently. Else, feel free to write your own answer below and even accept it.

Comment: @zeffii yes please mark this as a duplicate, thanks!